# Create New Objects in New Table During RealmJS Migration

Tags: javascript, realm

Error on Realm Migration in Xcode `com.facebook.JavaScript(11):EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,address=0x20)`

**Realm Schemas**

Schema v1:

- Car

  - id: string (primary key)
  - make: string
  - model: string
  - year: int
  - color: string
  - owner: string

Schema v2:

- Car (remains unchanged)
- CarTitle (new RealmObject added in v2)

  - id: string (primary key)
  - make: string
  - year: int
  - color: string
  - owner: string
  - registrationValid: type: string, optional: true

Realm Migration function for v1 -> v2:

```
export function migration(oldRealm: Realm, newRealm: Realm) {
    const oldCars = oldRealm.objects(Car.schema.name) as Realm.Results<Car>;

    oldCars.forEach((car: any) => {
        const carTitle = {
            id: car.id,
            make: car.make,
            year: car.year,
            owner: car.owner,
        } as CarTitle;

        newRealm.create(CarTitle.schema.name, carTitle, true);
    });
}
```

The error is thrown by the `newRealm.create()`. Is it not possible to create new objects in a new realm table from an old realm object during migration?

Comment: Realm does not have such a restriction. I have added an extra test: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/pull/1454